# Using Harvard Style

Tags: citing, natbib, harvard-style

Hi I'm using the Havard Style and want to cite a journal, not the author.
I'm using `natbib` and `har2nat` (because hyperlink didn't work with `harvard.sty`, and there are some problems with german citation, too).

I tried the `\DeclareCiteCommand`, but it didn't work because biblatex is missing.

My goal is to get something like "Guardian (2009)" in contrast to the author and the year.

Hope anyone can help me :)

**EDIT 2: Thanks to the advice in the comments, I would like to have a cite like "Guardian, Author (2008)" or "Author, Guardian (2008)".**

EDIT with minimal working example (the dcugerman.bst I got from [this source](http://wiki.wiba10.de/tech%3alatex%3azitierung_literaturverzeichnis))

```
\documentclass{article}
       \usepackage{hyperref}

        \usepackage{natbib}
        \setcitestyle{aysep={,}} % needed to fully emulate harvard's "dcu" citation style
        \usepackage{har2nat}
        \providecommand\harvardand{}
        \renewcommand{\harvardand}{und} 

        \usepackage{filecontents}

        \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
            @article{Gua2009,
              author = {Author, A.},
              year = {2008},
              title = {Some relevant article},
              journal = {Guardian}
            }
        \end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    This is a source from the Guardian\cite{Gua2009}

    \bibliographystyle{dcugerman}
    \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The Result is:

> This is a source from the Guardian(Author, 2008)
>
> References Author, A. (2008). Some relevant article, Guardian .

But I want someting like this:

> This is a source from the Guardian(Guardian, 2008)
>
> References Author, A. (2008). Some relevant article, Guardian .

EDIT 3 // MY SOLUTION

I just changed the author and journal entry in my bib file. (Thanks to Mico for the advice!)
If I have two newspaper articles from the same year, there will be a letter after the year so you can find the source in the bibliography.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: okay, thanks! I hope my MWE is understandable...

Comment: It's not really clear how readers will be able to find the citation in the bibliography, since you give them almost no clue. If the bibliography is very long, it will be impossible to find what article you refer to with (Guardian, 2008).

Comment: that's a really good adivce! I forgot that there are no links in the printed document :D Is it possible to show the author and the journal in the citation?

Answer (score 1):

You could define an "alias" for a certain entry and then cite it via `\citetalias` and `\citepalias`. For instance:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Gua2009,
      author = {Author, A.},
      year = {2009},
      title = {Some relevant article},
      journal = {Guardian},
      volume  = "",
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib,har2nat}
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}}
\providecommand\harvardand{}
\renewcommand\harvardand{und} 
\defcitealias{Gua2009}{Guardian, 2009} % define the alias to suit your needs
\bibliographystyle{dcugerman}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\citetalias{Gua2009}, \citepalias{Gua2009}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks good, but I have more than 30 sources. I would like to use a more "automatic" way...

Comment: @Mary - Something I don't understand about your setup is the way you're listing a regular author for a given entry *and* yet prefer to cite it by the name of the newspaper in which the entry was published. For newspaper articles, it's much more common to treat the newspaper itself as the author. (By the way, the `@article` entry type isn't all that well suited for articles published in *newspapers*.) If your concern is mostly about citing newspaper articles, I think you're better off defining the newspaper itself to be the "author" and use the `\citet` and `\citep` commands directly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I now exchange the author and journal entries :)